# serve static directory from mojolicious other than /public

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I have looked at a [variety](https://alisterwest.com/code/perl-mojolicious-serve-static) of [places](http://blogs.perl.org/users/revlin_john/2013/03/re-simple-webserver---serve-static-files-with-mojolicious.html) to find the best way to serve a directory of static files from within a [mojolicious](/questions/tagged/mojolicious) app and this is as close as I've been able to get:

```
package ExampleServer;
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious';
use Mojolicious::Static;

# This method will run once at server start
sub startup {
    my $self = shift;

    $ENV{MOJO_REVERSE_PROXY} = 1;

    # TODO: generalize
    my $static_path = '/www/example/docroot/.well-known/acme-challenge/';

    # Router
    my $r = $self->routes;

    # Normal route to controller
    $r->get('/')->to('example#welcome');

    # serve static directory
    $r->get('/.well-known/acme-challenge/*filename' => sub {
        my $self = shift;
        my $filename = $self->stash('filename');
        my $fqfn = $static_path . $filename;
        $self->app->log->debug($fqfn);
        my $static = Mojolicious::Static->new( paths => [ $static_path ] );

        $static->serve($self, $fqfn);
        $self->rendered;
    });
}

1;
```

This is pulling out the filename correctly and it only effects the URL's I want it to, but it serves empty files regardless of whether they exist in that directory or not.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly simplest way is use plugin [RenderFile](http://search.cpan.org/~koorchik/Mojolicious-Plugin-RenderFile-0.03/README.pod):

```
package ExampleServer;
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious';
use Mojolicious::Static;

# This method will run once at server start
sub startup {
   my $self = shift;

   $self->plugin('RenderFile');

   $ENV{MOJO_REVERSE_PROXY} = 1;

   # TODO: generalize
   my $static_path = '/www/example/docroot/.well-known/acme-challenge/';

   # Router
   my $r = $self->routes;

   # Normal route to controller
   $r->get('/')->to('example#welcome');

   # serve static directory
   $r->get('/.well-known/acme-challenge/*filename' => sub {
       my $self = shift;
       my $filename = $self->stash('filename');
       my $fqfn = $static_path . $filename;
       $self->app->log->debug($fqfn);
       $self->render_file(filepath=> $fqfn, format => 'txt', content_disposition => 'inline' );
   });
}
```

Or you can get inspiration from [source](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/KOORCHIK/Mojolicious-Plugin-RenderFile-0.03/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/RenderFile.pm).